# Relocated ffmpeg example files fail

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use some ffmpeg calls in my own program, the basis of which I'm editing the ffmpeg example program remuxing.c. I'm trying to use some of the ffmpeg calls in my own program.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 on a generic Linux box.

To help better understand what I've done and where I've having problems, I'll out line what I've done and what is not working.

Steps I've successfully completed:

-- I've have downloaded the ffmpeg code base and example files

-- Next I did a './configure', then 'make', then 'make install' and       'make examples' to make the libraries and examples

-- I tested some of the examples and they ran fine from the default       install directory

-- specifically, when I test remuxing.c in the original ffmpeg       downloaded dir — compile and run —  it works fine

```
    ./remuxing /data/iphone-h264.m4v /tmp/test15.ts
```

-- this creates a .ts output file that I can test and is readable by vlc

Having ensured that I correctly compiled and tested ffmpeg source and its example files, I next move to working my own program based on the example remuxing.c

— I copied the original remuxing.c into my own test directory structure

— I make it by running this to link in the required ffmpeg libraries (I think)

```
    cc -DLINUX -o remuxing remuxing.c -I ../ffmpeg/libavformat -lavformat -I ../ffmpeg/libavcodec -lavcodec -I ../ffmpeg/libswresample -lswresample -I ../ffmpeg/libavutil -lavutil -lpthread -lm
```

— however when I try to generate a test16.ts file (to know it is different from the one I created before) I get an error:

```
    ./remuxing /data/iphone-h264.m4v /tmp/test16.ts
    Could not open input file '/data/iphone-h264.m4v’ Error occurred: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is the exact same video file the same program converted from the installed doc/examples directory.

**QUESTION** — why is this happening — what am I doing wrong?

I guess I may not be properly linking in the ffmpeg libraries?? -- but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I can also post my makefiles if that would help.

Would be most appreciative for any help -- thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty clear.  Have you verified the target file is not already open somewhere else when it is accessed by your process?  Is the file location correct?  Has the file been corrupted somehow by being processed by other source code before being used here?

Comment: Thanks for your Q's -- yes file is in the correct location, is valid, is not in use by another process or program & as I indicated in the post above both the original file and the generated .ts file have been tested / validated against VLC. Any other thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My only guesses are in my comments, but the title description _relocated_ still makes me wish I were there to look at the issue.  It appears you've documented the problem well, but something must be missing.  In any case, I do not know what else it could be.   One thing I see in looking again:  Is `/tmp/test16.ts` an absolute location, or relative?  If relative, then `./tmp/test16.ts` might make a difference.  (preceding dot).  Same with `/data/iphone-h264.m4v`

Comment: ...And yes, I see in your text that all things being equal from one try to the next, it should work, but I see a lot of `../` and `./` and `/` directory references.  It's hard know if one of them could be pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: Thanks again. Here's some updated info:

Comment: Thanks again. Here's some updated info: Yes, they are absolute & looking at the same place. Seems when I build it in my directory, it's not using the new libraries but some older ones from July.

I did a './configure --libdir=/usr --shlibdir=/usr/lib' then 'make' and 'make install' to try to force the new ones into /usr/lib. Didn't work but now when I try recompiling _in_the_examples_ directory, I can link in my library & seems to be ok. 
Q - what ./configure switches R needed to get the libraries to install in /usr/lib so they can be linked in via '-lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat'. ?